# Embedded DocuSign signing: using recipient's language

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign's REST API to create envelopes in embedded signing mode.
I authenticate the signers on my website, then ask DocuSign for recipient view. Users can sign documents, that's ok.

My problem is: the embedded signing view is in english, whereas my users may speak other languages.
As an example, how to redirect signers to embedded signing view in french?

I saw "emailNotification" option when adding signers to an envelope (https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm). But it looks like it is about language of email notifications sent by DocuSign to signers. I guess it does not apply to my use case, because I use embedded signing mode, where my website sends email notifications, DocuSign doesn't.

Note: I do not want to translate the documents in envelope. I want signers to display DocuSign's user interface using their native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the "emailNotification" language **does** also control the language the signer gets in the UI when they are signing.  It's not documented that way but I have it working.  Yes it's odd because for an embedded scenario you'd assume you have no need to set that value.

You might need to make sure you have "Set Recipient Sign Language" checked under Preferences -> Features.  I recall that I needed to have DocuSign enable that so I could see it as an admin, then check it.  That, combined with setting the language inside "emailNotification" did work.

** Update **

For new Docusign UI, the setting is under: Admin >> Sending Settings >> Fields and Properties >> Enable custom email and language for each recipient

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign supports most languages for signers via a UI user control at the bottom of the screen that allows the user to choose the language, including you when testing. The assumption is that setting the emial notification language means that user is using that language and thus the "browser default" will already be set to that language.

You DO NOT set the language that the browser will view the envelope in, only email noticifications, the user/signer sets that in the browser (known in the drop down mentioned as browser default) or by manually selecting what language they want to view the signing experience in.

Here is a link to the supported language documentation https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/documentation/cdse-user-guide/console-overview/supported-languages

Answer (score 1):

Response #2 above no longer work on my case instead on the Summer '15 release, the language parameter should be appended to the response URL.

This is done by appending a locale parameter (&locale={languageCode}) to the URL provided in the response to a POST recipient view request before loading it in your iframe or web control/view.

eg:

https://demo.docusign.net/signing/startinsession.aspx?t=d1cf42f2-30b6-499b-ab54-058fbf438103&locale=fr