# How do I change language on DocuSign e-mails?

Tags: rest, email, docusignapi

I have set a simple template DocuSign for my client.
I use this template to send request signature with the REST API.

The body and the object mail are been modified in the request :

```
 {
[...]
  "emailSubject" : "Document à signer",
  "emailBlurb" : "Merci.",
[...]
}
```

But, for now, the e-mail are in English.. Can I change the language on French ?

I read it is possible to personalize  the language of each recipient but for that, I must modify the request.
Is it possible to change the language without personalize  the language of each recipient

Thanks in advance,

Frédéric.

Comment: You have the option to set it on a recipient level in your call, not envelope wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please search for previously asked questions under the #DocuSignAPI tag as this has been answered before.  Take a look at the [API Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation) in the Developer Center and do a search for `emailNotification`.  You'll see how to set language through there.

Take a look at this previous post:

[Embedded DocuSign signing: using recipient's language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785088/embedded-docusign-signing-using-recipients-language)

You should also take a look at the [Signer Resource File](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-signing-resource-file-information.pdf#page=6) which allows additional language settings.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I said, I know It is possible to set the language with emailNotification. But, is it possible to change the language with the administration panel ?