# Changing a locale for embedded signing

Tags: ruby, docusignapi

How can I change a locale for embedded signing via API for each unique recipient? Currently I use a query parameter which I add to embedded signing URL - "&locale={lang}", but I guess there should be some option in API(Ruby SDK) for it.

In previous answers I saw "emailNotification" object and "language"(or smth similar) as its key, but in the current version of SDK it seems not to exist any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question [Embedded DocuSign signing: using recipient's language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785088/embedded-docusign-signing-using-recipients-language)
The emailNotification property for each recipient (Signer etc.) can be used to specify supported languages.
Note that if they already set their lang themselves - this may override your API request.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've looked through once more and found that property in REST API. Now it's only needed to find it in SDK.

Comment: Each recipient type has it. Here is the Signer one - https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client/blob/a8c9654f8820ff5266d606e3295c1558640fd895/lib/docusign_esign/models/signer.rb
 :'email_notification' => :'emailNotification'